# when i use hover for element with box-sizing and padding and min-width, its automatically changed

Tags: html, css

When I hover over my element, it switches from a 1px red border to a 2px blue border.

I used `box-sizing` and `min-width`, but `box-sizing` is not working when I hover over it; the element gets wider. In this case, I can't use fixed width because the text in every element is different. How can I prevent the width changing when I hover over it?

This is my code:

```css
{
    min-width: 10px;
    padding: 12px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid red;

    &:hover {
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include your HTML and compiled CSS in a Stack Snippet. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have hard to comprehend.. what result are you after? blue, or red border?

Answer (score 1):

`min-width` needs to be larger than `border-left-width` + `padding-left` + `padding-right` + `border-right-width`.

```css
.box{display: inline-block;min-width:50px;min-height:50px;padding:12px;box-sizing:border-box;border:1px solid red;}
.box:hover{border:5px solid blue;}
```

```html
<label class="box"/>
```

Comment: i solved this problem by inner border :)
thx for your answer